# Json deserializer OR Regex Or Json parsing to convert a Json string in c#

Tags: c#, json, regex, deserialization, string-parsing

I have following Json file which i want to convert to a different format. New format shown below.
 Can we use Json Parsing for this? or can we use Regular expression to change the modify the json string.

We can also use custom json deserializer i think. Can someone help me with some easy way to do this?

Current format

```
 {
"PRETEST":
{"response":
{"a":{"source":"VeD","name":"a","value":null},
"b":{"source":"VeD","name":"b","value":"2XX"},
"c":{"source":"VeD","name":"c","value":"4933011630372431565180"},
"d":{"source":"VeD","name":"d","value":null},
"e":{"source":"VeD","name":"e","value":"EHD453REN00000004"},
"f":{"source":"VeD","name":"f","value":"HU55"},
"g":{"source":"VeD","name":"g","value":"453"},
"h":{"source":"VeD","name":"h","value":null},
"i":{"source":"VeD","name":"i","value":null}},
"httpcode":200},
"TEST":
{"response":
{"a":{"source":"VeD","name":"a","value":null},
"b":{"source":"VeD","name":"b","value":"3XX"},
"c":{"source":"VeD","name":"c","value":"5933011630372431565180"},
"d":{"source":"VeD","name":"d","value":null},
"e":{"source":"VeD","name":"e","value":"FHD453REN00000004"},
"f":{"source":"VeD","name":"f","value":"HU55"},
"g":{"source":"VeD","name":"g","value":"433"},
"h":{"source":"VeD","name":"h","value":null},
"i":{"source":"VeD","name":"i","value":null}},
"httpcode":200},
"INT":
{"response":
{"a":{"source":"VeD","name":"a","value":null},
"b":{"source":"VeD","name":"b","value":"4XX"},
"c":{"source":"VeD","name":"c","value":"1933011630372431565180"},
"d":{"source":"VeD","name":"d","value":null},
"e":{"source":"VeD","name":"e","value":"KHD453REN00000004"},
"f":{"source":"VeD","name":"f","value":"KU55"},
"g":{"source":"VeD","name":"g","value":"253"},
"h":{"source":"VeD","name":"h","value":null},
"i":{"source":"VeD","name":"i","value":null}},
"httpcode":200}}
```

New Format

```
{
"PRETEST":
{"response":
{"a"null,
"b":"2XX",
"c":"4933011630372431565180",
"d"::null,
"e":"EHD453REN00000004",
"f":"HU55",
"g":"453",
"h"::null,
"i"::null},
"httpcode":200},
"TEST":
{"response":
{"a":null,
"b""3XX"
"c":"5933011630372431565180",
"d":null,
"e""FHD453REN00000004",
"f""HU55",
"g""433",
"h":null,
"i":null},
"httpcode":200},
"INT":
{"response":
{"a":null,
"b""4XX",
"c":"1933011630372431565180",
"d":null,
"e":"KHD453REN00000004",
"f":"KU55",
"g":"253",
"h":null,
"i":null},
"httpcode":200},
"PREPROD":
{"response":
{"a":null,
"b":"5XX",
"c":"8933011630372431565180",
"d":null,
"e":"EHD453REN00000004",
"f":"HU55",
"g":"453",
"h":null,
"i":null},
"httpcode":200}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regular expression solution.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"\{[^{}]+value\":([^{}]+)\}";
      string replacement = "$1";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string input = YOUR_JSON_STRING;
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
      Console.WriteLine(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: string pattern = "\\{[^{}]+value\":([^{}]+)\\}"; .. works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. Go to this website (http://jsonutils.com/) and make corresponding classes with the corresponding data annotations and finally, by using NewtonSoft (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), render your json.

Comment: i need to do this programatically..Can you give sample code for this?